# java objects, do I create an animal or a dog with animal speedy = new dog(); and why?

Tags: java, object

I don't get what I'm creating actually... 
Usually you create an object with `dog speedy = new dog();`
you call the constructor `dog()` which creates a `dog` object and `speedy` is the name of the reference to it. but what if the first dog is named "animal" (`dog` extends `animal`) ?

Comment: I do hope that your classes are named in `PascalCase`...

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear, but if your Dog class is extending Animal, and you want to use the Dog methods/fields, you need to create a new Dog. You could create an Animal a = new Dog() but you still won't be able to access the Dog methods/fields (although it shouldn't throw an error)

Comment: I'll show you an example: at the very bottom you can see "Alpha delta = new Delta()" and my question is: am I creating an alpha or delta?   http://files.irq0.org/java/aufgaben_2007-09-10_loesungen.pdf

Comment: The name delta has nothing to do with it really and is just confusing you I think. But assuming it's not throwing an error, Delta implements/extends Alpha, so you're creating a Delta but can only access the features defined in Alpha.

Comment: why can I only access the features defined in alpha? what's the difference between Delta delta = new Delta() and Alpha delta = new Delta() ?

Comment: Because you can't access methods not defined in the type. In this case the type is Alpha (Alpha delta). If that code works it means Delta extends/implements Alpha, but you would need to use the Delta type to take advantage of what it implements additionally.

Comment: @Brian96 what you are missing is that `Dog` _is an_ `Animal`! `Delta` _is an_ `Alpha`! The answer is therefore both!

Answer (score 2):

### Static vs dynamic type of an object

Consider the following classes:

```
class Animal {
    void eat() { System.out.println("Nom nom"); }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    void eat() { System.out.println("I want a bone"); }
    void bark() { System.out.println("WOOF"); }
}
```

Now consider the following code:

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
```

Question: what is the type of the variable `dog`? The answer depends on whether you want to know the static type or the dynamic type.

**Static type** is the type the compiler sees, which is `Animal` in this case. This is also the type of the variable. This will define which methods are available.

**Dynamic type** is the type that is defined at runtime, it is the "real" type of the variable, which defines its behaviour.

In the above code you will not be able to call `bark()` on variable `dog`, because its static type is `Animal`. However, when you call `eat()`, it will return `I want a bone` because its behaviour is defined by its dynamic type which is `Dog`.

In many cases you do not know the dynamic type of an object. For example if you write a method that has a parameter of type `List`, the actual dynamic type will be known only when someone calls your method with a `List` implementation (such as `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` etc.).

Comment: ok, Animal dog = new Dog(); means that I am creating an object with the type Dog and dog is the reference to this object, but I can only access methods which have the same name like the ones in the class Animal?

Comment: @Brian96 yes. it will behave as a `Dog`, but you can only access methods of  `Animal`.

Comment: okay... I don get the exception 100%  though why I still can access the eat method from Dog when I''m referring exclusively to Animal

Comment: @Brian96 Because `eat()` is defined in `Animal` too.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the way in which you would like to use your dog object. Consider this example:

```
class Animal {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.writeln("nam nam nam");
    }
    public void sleep() {
        System.out.writeln("zzzz zzzz");
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    public void bark() {
        System.out.writeln("ruff ruff");
    }
}
```

If you want to treat your dog like the rest of the animals, i.e. as someone who can eat and sleep, you do this:

```
Animal fifi = new Dog();
fifi.eat();   // Works fine
fifi.sleep(); // Works fine
fifi.bark();  // Compile error!
```

However, Fifi cannot bark. If you do this, on the other hand,

```
Dog speedy = new Dog();
speedy.eat();
speedy.sleep();
speedy.bark();
```

your `Dog` would be able to bark, in addition to also being able to eat and sleep, like the rest of the animals.

Comment: mal kurz auf Deutsch wegen der Verständlichkeit... das Animal bzw Dog am Anfang der Zeile jeweils sagt aus, von welcher Klasse mein erzeugtes Sog-Objekt auf die Methoden zugreifen kann?

Comment: @Brian96 Entschuldigen Sie mir bitte, ich spreche Deutsch nicht (despite [my user name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights) giving a wrong impression).

Comment: no worries haha, what I was trying to say is: so the Animal or Dog at the very beginning of each line is defining, from which class I can use it's methods with my Dog object?

Comment: @Brian96 The type in front of the variable name determines the *static* type of that variable (i.e. the type known to the compiler, at compile time, as opposed to the type known to Java Virtual Machine, at runtime). This type determines the methods that you can call and the variables that you can access directly, without a cast. Accessing other methods would require a cast, e.g. `((Dog)fifi).bark();` is going to compile and run correctly, because you provide the compiler with the more specific type.